# JSF change locale for a sub-section of a page

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, localization, internationalization

I need to display most of the page in the users selected locale but display a section of the page in another locale. Basically a some point in the .xhtml, I want to set a new local for that part of the page and then at a later point switch back to the users locale. I've tried the following hacks:

1. Nesting `<f:view locale="subsectionlocale">`
2. Resetting the session dynamically in a getter at the start of the section (I said it was a hack).

Neither of these do what I'm hoping (as might be expected).  Any ideas on a proper solution or working hack?

Comment: Not sure what exactly you're hoping, but you can use `<f:loadBundle>` to explicitly load a specific bundle. Is this indeed what you're looking for?

Comment: @BalusC that may be part of the solution but what I want is a section of the .xhtml to be displayed in a different locale than the rest of the page.